# what is the application of "::date" in redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I see somewhere in the sql code in Amazon redshift that ::date is used when comparing two dates. I am wondering is there any difference between these three lines of code:

```
start_date < '2016-01-01'
start_date < '2016-01-01'::date
start_date < date('2016-01-01')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The result is the same in all three cases.

Specifically:

- `start_date < '2016-01-01'` is trying to compare a `date` with a `varchar`, but Amazon Redshift is smart enough to convert the `varchar` into a date format for comparison purposes.
- `start_date < '2016-01-01'::date` is doing a proper comparison between two `date` fields. This would be equivalent to `date '2016-01-01'`.
- `start_date < date('2016-01-01')` appears to also be comparing `date` fields, although that syntax isn't in the [Date and Time Functions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/Date_functions_header.html) documentation.

A more useful example of using `::date` is when comparing two timestamps, and you only wish to compare the date, for example:

```
select end::date - start::date as days FROM table
```