# Redshift: Date Comparisons for a Javascript time format Varchar field

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm new to Redshift and am trying to write a query which will return records where a field contains a date value within the last 30 days.

This works:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE deactivated < GETDATE() LIMIT 10;
```

I get 10 rows returned, all in the past. The field `deactivated` is stored as varchar(32) containing JavaScript format timestamps, e.g. `2018-06-27T14:30:18.2457388Z`.

However, this doesn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE deactivated >= DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE());
```

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41662911/what-is-the-application-of-date-in-redshift) but it doesn't really help with the above. What's the best way to query between dates stored in this format?

Thanks.

Comment: How does your query not work?  What does that mean?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - thank you for your nudge, that did the trick for me, I think I was seeing some timeout problems.

Answer (score 0):

The second above query *does* work. I will leave it up in case it helps anyone else.